# How do you sort a dictionary by key, and return the entire dictionary with both key and value?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Heres what I have:

```
 dict = {'b':[456], 'a': [123]}

 sort_dict = sorted(dict.items(), key = str)
 return sort_dict
```

What my code returns:

```
[('a', [123]), ('b', [456])]
```

what I need it to return:

```
{'a':[123], 'b':[456]}
```

I know I can make a for loop or something to make a new dict, but is there another/simpler way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=str))
OrderedDict([('a', [123]), ('b', [456])])
```

For Python 3.6+ this is enough (read comments for more details):

```
d = {'b':[456], 'a': [123]}

>>> dict(sorted(d.items(), key=str))
{'a': [123], 'b': [456]}
```

Don't name your variables `dict`, `list`, `str`, etc. as these are the names of the [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html).

Comment: Note: This behavior is only applicable to Python 3.6 and up (and [it isn't actually guaranteed by the 3.6 spec](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation), though it happens to work on CPython). Prior to 3.6, `dict` order had very little to do with the order in which keys were created (and for `str` keys, varied from run to run).